# Convert Text file to XML file

Tags: xml, text-files

I want to parse the content of the text file which is in the below format

example of  text file data

```
key1:value1
key2:value2
key3:value3
```

Now I want the above content to be parsed with the key-value format and make an xml file from this text file.

example of xml file data (I want this type of format)

```
<string name="key1">value1</string>
<string name="key2">vaue2</string>
<string name="key3">value3</string>
```

This should either be done through a script file in windows or command prompt.

could you please add one have a better idea how to solve on this issue or could you please provide me a example code or link of tutorials?

Comment: Why is this tagged as an Android question?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is trivial using a program called [awk](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm)

```
$ awk -F: 'BEGIN{print"<data>"} {printf"<string name=\"%s\">%s</string>\n",$1,$2} END{print"</data>"}' input.txt
<data>
<string name="key1">value1</string>
<string name="key2">value2</string>
<string name="key3">value3</string>
</data>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/). Here's an Ant target that does what you ask for:

```
<target name="text2xml">
    <copy file="originalfile.txt" tofile="xmlfile.xml" overwrite="true"/>
    <replaceregexp file="xmlfile.xml"
                   match="(.*):(.*)"
                   replace='&lt;string name="\1"&gt;\2&lt;/string&gt;'
                   byline="true"/>

</target>
```